# Stop Automatic Lead Email

Tags: python, email, odoo, openerp-7

We are using OpenERP 7 to manage leads within our organisation.

Leads are created by incoming emails.  When assigning to a different sales person, the sales person gets an email with the original email and the from address is the original person that emailed it.

This is a problem because it looks like the customer emailed them directly and encourages the sales person to manage the lead from their email, rather than sending responses from the OpenERP system.  How can I stop this email from being sent?   I want to make my own template and use an automatic action to send a notification.

There is no automatic action sending this email.  I believe it is somewhere in the python code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the automated actions from OpenERP in the Settings/Technical/Scheduler/Scheduled Actions menu. Look for the actions that read incoming e-mails and de-activate it.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the automated actions and there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I saw an option in the Settings / Configuration / Sales menu. At the bottom of the page, you must have a group called 'Emails Integration' and in this group, you must have a line with a checked checkbox with 'Create leads from incoming mails' as label.

Uncheck this box and click on 'Apply' button at the top of the page.[image]

Comment: Yea, that's the step to create leads from incoming mails.  I want the leads to still come in.  But when the lead get assigned to a sales person, the original email with the original from address gets sent to the sales person with no mention of the ERP system. To the sales person, it appears that the person emailed them directly.  I found a hack solution which I will add.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack solution which I hope someone can improve.

Basically the email comes in and adds an entry to the table `mail_message`.  The `type` is set as "email" and this seems to be the issue.  If I change it to "notification", the original email does not get sent to the newly assigned salesperson which is the behaviour that I want.

Create a server action on the incoming email server that executes the following python code:

> cr.execute("UPDATE mail_message SET type = 'notification' WHERE model = 'crm.lead' AND res_id = %s AND type = 'email' ", (object.id, ))